# Django Bootboxjs shows nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I can't run it.
I've added a file to my js folder.
I connected it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootbox.min.js' %}"></script>
```

I have done like that with other files so I think this like works.

I've tryed simple code from a page, but there is no dialog.

```
    <p>Content here. <a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a></p>

<!-- JS dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootbox code -->
<script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
        bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
            console.log("Alert Callback");
        });
    });
</script>
```